# Cannot bind query parameter; Unknown name basicRequest when retrieving basic insights for a location

Tags: google-my-business-api

I'm trying to retrieve insights for a location using the Google Business Profile API. I've tried a few approaches, but I always get an error about "Cannot bind query parameter".

According to the docs, I should be posting to this URL: https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/xxx/locations:reportInsights

and in the body, pass in an array of locationNames, but when I do that, I get the error about "Cannot bind query parameter 'locationNames'".

So I just tried doing a GET on this URL and pass in the names on the name querystring and that worked just fine to get the high-level data.

https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/xxx/locations:reportInsights?name=accounts/xxx/locations/xxx

So I know I have the right account ID, location ID, etc. But I need to be able to add in the basicRequest parameter so I can indicate which metric that I want to retrieve.

So I've POST to both of those URLS above with a body that looks like this:

{"basicRequest":{"metricRequests":[{"metric":"ALL"}],"timeRange":{"startTime":"2020-10-12T01:01:23.045123456Z","endTime":"2022-01-10T23:59:59.045123456Z"}}}

But again, I get the same errors about "Cannot bind query parameter" to field "basicRequest" (Same as when I tried to pass in the "locationNames" param in the JSON.

So clearly, I'm doing something wrong with how I am sending in the parameters in the body because it doesn't seem to think any of those parameter names are valid. My end goal is to be able to retrieve queries_direct, actions_total, etc.

I'm using Ruby, and there isn't a client library for it, so I'm just crafting the URLs and the JSON body and doing a GET or POST to it.

Greatly appreciate any pointers!